# Deploying webapp in Tomcat6

Tags: java, deployment, tomcat

I have the following problem. When I developed my application locally I was deploying it using Netbeans support. Now I need to deploy the application on the official server. I installed Tomcat6 and it displays the start page properly but how to deploy my app? Which changes are needed to make ot work on port 80 (at the moment it works on default 8080)? Where should I copy the files from my application? Thanks a lot for helping me out. Links to similar posts are also appreciated. I could not find any that would help me tough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how to deploy my app

Netbeans on build operation creates a war file in dist folder. See a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007346/how-can-i-create-a-war-file-of-my-project-in-netbeans) about it here. You will need to take this war file and:

> Where should I copy the files from my
>   application?

put it under webapp folder in tomcat. 
The location is your tomcat_home folder->webapps.

> Which changes are needed to make to
>   work on port 80

under your tomcat_home folder, open conf folder. Inside, find server.xml file. open it with notepad and change the port number from 8080 to 80:

```
<Connector port="8080" … />
```

should be:

```
<Connector port="80" … />
```

Don't forget to restart the server!

Now the link to your application will be:
http://localhost/YourWarFileName/
or the computer ip/name instead of localhost.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Odelya. Do I have to copy any jar files? What about web.xml which is located in my WEB-INF directory? Any changes are needed there?

Comment: You don't need to copy the jar files. 
The war file includes them.
as well, the web.xml will be deployed.

Comment: If you are interested to see the war file, copy it to a different location. right click->rename to youfile.zip and extract all files.

You will see how war looks like inside.

Comment: Thanks. It seems to work but now I have a problem with Hibernate but that's for a different post I guess. Your information was very helpful.

Comment: You are welcomed:) in stackoverflow, if the answer helped you, you click on the V sign next to the answer to mark it with green as the right answer. I will appreciate it..