# Deploying a servlet/jsp project made in netbeans in a different ubuntu system

Tags: tomcat, ubuntu, netbeans, deployment

I created a web project in netbeans, which involves usage of various APIs. So all those libraries are linked as jar files and used to create class files which are imported in the serlet/jsp pages to make the system work.

Now, the problem that I face is how to deploy this in another system? I have a server in which I would like to host this system and test it live.

Running from netbeans is successful, but am unable to move the files and run it in the other system. For testing purposes I am using an ubuntu desktop edition and trying to figure out how this work.

I read about war file placement and stuff, I tried moving the build\web folder. But, I got confused with moving the library files and stuff. All in all am totally clueless in 
how to shift the netbeans project to a different ubuntu system and run it?

Comment: You shouldn't run the netbeans project. You should generate a war file from netbeans, and deploy that war file in any tomcat you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the jar files your project depends on identified in NetBeans, you should be able to "deploy" to a war file that contains all your code and dependent libraries in one archive that you drop in the "webapps" folder of a Tomcat installation, for example.

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007346/how-can-i-create-a-war-file-of-my-project-in-netbeans)