"Tomcat with the same Catalina Home folder is already registered."
I'm still new to programming, and as much as I tried to find a solution online, I couldn't find anyone giving an answer to this problem.
Basically I'm running "Apache NetBeans IDE 18" with Tomcat version 10.1. I first tried to port a code so I could practice for a test, then noticed the "Javax doesn't exist" error, leading me to finding out I have to use the Tomcat library, and I made a test servlet and used the Tomcat folder as my server location. It worked and I resolved the Javax issue by replacing it with Jakarta, and as I started to go back to the original code, hoping to "resolve the server issue", this message pops up:
ignore the weird Tomcat folder name..
Has anyone else run into this issue before? And if so, could you please help out?
I tried to do the same thing I did with the first project where I used the tomcat folder as a server location, not knowing I could have only one location at a time. I tried making a new project and closing the test one, yet nothing works.
I tried installing and using Tomcat version 11, and as a result NetBeans immediately requested yet another server for me, and after I selected the folder again, I got the same message: "Tomcat with the same Catalina Home folder is already registered."
I tried deleting the test project, and yet the previous tomcat version is still "already registered".

What does the Tools|Servers menu have to say? ...then noticed the "Javax doesn't exist" error I'll take a gues that it's the javax.servlet package versus jakarta.servlet issue. You should be using the second one now

Jakarta/javax isn't the issue. I already did that in the test project. My only issue is that netbeans is literally not allowing me to select a Tomcat server since both versions are "already registered". Even having swapped javax with jakarta, it still doesn't do anything about my server problem...

I mentioned that en passant. Just delete any servers that are listed and start again

My answer below is actually a comment, it has been written in the answer box for the below reason. However, it should be considered as a comment, not an answer as @g00se has observed below

Are you using Maven or gradle? There are plugins for both to run jetty. I find jetty easier to use to run from an IDE and debug / develop. I do use Tomcat for actual standalone servers.

I’ve not used NetBeans in years, but… generally in an IDE you must first establish an entry within the IDE to identify an external app server such as Tomcat. This step makes your IDE aware of that app server. You could have multiple entries here, for different app servers or even different versions of an app server. Then secondly within your project you establish a reference to the IDE’s entry that identifies your desired server to be used to run your app. I suspect you have (a) conflated these two concepts, and (b) created two of the first entries both pointing to the very same Tomcat.

This is not an answer, more of a suggestion
In my experience (my view) using Tomcat from within an IDE is error prone. Most of the time it works; however, there are also many instances where the IDE gives errors which are very difficult to resolve.
There are many reasons for that, sometime web apps don't unload properly, directories don't get cleared, hot deployment is done by the IDE where the web app generates errors, directories get locked.
A better solution I found during development is to use a standalone Tomcat from the console with the WAR file exported from the IDE.
The Tomcat can be shutdown, error traces can be directly seen on the console or log files, configuration files can be changed easily.
My suggestion would be to use a standalone Tomcat for experimentation & development.
Tomcat can be downloaded from here

Unzip the Tomcat
Set JAVA_HOME environment variable to the directory where JDK has been installed (not the bin directory, the directory just above that)
Add the JDK bin directory to the PATH
java -version to check it once.
Export WAR file from NetBeans and place it in the tomcat/webapps directory
Start the Tomcat from console

Give it a try.

This is not an answer, more of a suggestion. It's probably better not to post it as an answer in that case. But  I concur with the content and will upvote it as a comment

@g00se, I did think of posting it as a comment; however the content is a bit longish and formatting can be done better in the answer box but I agree with you that this is actually a comment

I just tried this method, but when I tried to create a war file (by running dist target) netbeans just doesn't do anything, and I can't export the WAR file because I can't find one..

@MessaTee, are you using maven project structure

@Ironluca I'm pretty sure the answer is no? Does it help if I am, cause I don't know if I am using the maven project structure...

@MessaTee, I am not very familiar with NetBeans, however, it should be exporting a WAR file as per this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007346/how-can-i-create-a-war-file-of-my-project-in-netbeans

@Ironluca I looked in the files, I saw there was no dist, and I tried to make a dist file, but NetBeans literally didn't let me make one. Rather, it would do nothing upon me attempting to make one.

@MessaTee, since you are starting out, it probably would be worthwhile to explore Maven as it is one of popular build systems. Refer: https://maven.apache.org/
To give a small background, maven expects web app projects to be of a specific structure Refer: https://maven.apache.org/archetypes/maven-archetype-webapp/
A pom.xml file needs to be written listing the dependencies and other aspects Refer: https://maven.apache.org/pom.html
Then with console command WAR file can be exported to the ./dist folder which can be deployed on Tomcat
Give it a try
