What can cause the HTTP status 404 when running a Java EE web application in IntelliJ IDEA?
I'm trying to create a simple Java EE web application in IntelliJ IDEA according to this tutorial. I have made sure that everything necessary is installed on my computer (IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate incl. the relevant plugins, JDK, TomEE and therefore Tomcat). The tutorial is explained for Tomcat. However, I have decided to install TomEE. As far as I know, it should be installed correctly under the following path: /usr/local/tomee/apache-tomee-plume-10.0.0-M1.
When I start the server in terminal with the command ./catalina.sh start, this page is displayed in the browser: Apache Tomcat (TomEE) successfully installed
I followed the steps from the tutorial. I selected Jakarta EE 10 as the version and whenever Tomcat was selected in the tutorial, I used TomEE instead. In the Configuration settings I made sure that the URL (under Server settings) is the same as in the tutorial and under Deployment I added the artifact JavaEEHelloWorld:war exploded to fix the warning.
Server settings
Deployment settings
However, when running the configuration the artifact is built, but eventually the browser always shows me
HTTP Status 404 - not found
Type: Status Report
Description: The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.
---
Apache Tomcat (TomEE)/10.1.20 (10.0.0-M1)

I don't understand where the problem lies and how I can get the page to be generated and displayed correctly.
I haven't made any changes to the auto-generated directories or files: pom.xml, index.jsp, web.xml, HelloServlet.java
I checked to see if IntelliJ was showing me any problems. Nothing was displayed there. I checked my inputs several times. I also deleted the entire project and set it up a second time, but I ended up with the same result.
I've checked related questions. This pointed out that the servlet-api could be causing the problem. My Tomcat version is 10.1.20 which is why jakarta.servlet-api (instead of javax.servlet-api) should be used in the pom.xml. This is the case.
I tried to identify possible error sources and fix them: I looked at the directories via File | Project Structure under Modules and manually marked the srcfolder as Source Folder. Then I looked at Artifacts. I made sure that the JavaEEHelloWorld:war exploded artifact contained the correct directories and files. The directories WEB-INF and META-INF were present. However, I did not see the web.xml under the WEB_INF directory. I therefore added it manually via the + File.
Unfortunately, all attempts failed to prevent the error from being displayed. By now I have no idea what else I can do.

You could refer this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78571105/tomcat-with-the-same-catalina-home-folder-is-already-registered/78571451?noredirect=1#comment138519264_78571451 I have put in a suggestion, perhaps that could be of help to you. It does not answer your question though. It suggests an alternative

Does https://stackoverflow.com/a/66806790/104891 looks like your problem?

Thank you both very much! I fixed my problem by using Tomcat 9.0.89.
